# Boost Path not found, makefile

Tags: c++, windows, boost, git-bash

Keeps on saying that boost file does not exist. I am running on gitbash on Windows. The error is below. I don't know how to fix it, I have set include -I flag to my boost directories, and my environment path is also includes the boost directories.

```
make -f Makefile
g++ -O3 -std=c++14 -o Exp.o -c Exp.cpp -g -I/b/ProgramData/libtorch_2_10/include -I/b/ProgramData/libtorch_2_10/include/torch/csrc/api/include -I/b/'Program Files'/boost/boost_1_82_0/boost
Exp.cpp:7:10: fatal error: boost/algorithm/string.hpp: No such file or directory
    7 | #include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:38: Exp.o] Error 1
```

Comment: I'd guess change `-I/b/'Program Files'/boost/boost_1_82_0/boost` to `-I/b/'Program Files'/boost/boost_1_82_0`

Comment: Unrelated to the error, did you compile `boost_1_82_0` for MinGW? If you downloaded and installed a msvc binary it's not going to work for the compiled libraries in boost.

Comment: ***I don't know how to fix it*** How you fix this type of problem is to first check the absolute path of the header file (by appending the folder you told your compiler to look to the full path used in the #include) to make sure the Include directory you typed makes sense: So does the file: `/b/'Program Files'/boost/boost_1_82_0/boost/boost/algorithm/string.hpp` exist? You could check that with `ls -al  /b/'Program Files'/boost/boost_1_82_0/boost/boost/algorithm/string.hpp` If that is not correct where is the `string.hpp` file?

Comment: Yes the file exist, the file path exist. I have also tried installing boost through conda, which `conda install -c conda-forge boost` I am still getting the same error.